# Execute shell script with arguments using groovy script

Tags: groovy

Am trying to execute shell script using groovy. My shell script accepts arguments, if i hardcode them and execute, it works fine.

Please help in finding out how to pass those arguments from the variables and execute the script.

`def cmd= [ 'sh', '-c', 'cd <<Script Path>>;sh <<script_name>> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> <arg4>;exit'].execute()`

If i ran the above cmd, the script is not executed.

Thanks
Raam

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of the commands involved this question basically lacks the actual error.  Here is how you get them:

```
groovy:000> cmd.waitFor() // exitValue()
===> 1
groovy:000> cmd.errorStream.readLines()
...
```

Guess: wrong directory, wrong quoting of the arguments, wrong composition of the actual cmd string

Comment: def result = [ 'sh', '-c', 'cd /opt/local/xxxx/scripts;./export -export -out /opt/local/user/abc.xml -app abc/xyz -user user -pw pwd -domain TEST;exit' ].execute()
result.waitFor()
println result.text

If it ran this command it works fine, but how to pass these arguments from any variables.

Comment: e.g. use `"... -pwd '${thepassword}' ..."`; or any other means groovy provides to concat the string.